# How to downgrade to an older package if the package got superseded by a newer one in the apt repo?

Tags: apt, package-management, modem-manager

I have recently upgraded from ModemManager 1.16 to 1.18 via apt on Ubuntu Jammy, which turned out to be a huge mistake, as the new version introduces many bugs. I have now tried to remove version and reinstall version 1.16, but it seems like it is no longer available, [only versions 1.12 and 1.18 are available](https://packages.ubuntu.com/jammy/modemmanager).

I have found the following [launchpad archive](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/modemmanager/1.16.6-2), but it seems to only support Imprish while I am on Jammy.

How can I downgrade back to my desired version?

Comment: Can you please give a link where I can see that it has many bugs?

Comment: @vanadium unfortunately no, since the package doesn't exist in any apt repo anymore.

Comment: @David What do you mean? it is buggy for me specifically with my specific modem.

Comment: Please report a bug then. If the version you want specifically doesn't exist anymore in any online repository including 3rd party PPAs then you can't use apt, obviously. You'll have to find the source code and compile it yourself. Good luck with that.